# Uploading data takes ages, how can I improve?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a app ( swiftui ) that uses firebase as it’s backend, I upload all content to firestore and the app shows the files ( images, text and audio )

I have attached a image for reference

[image: image of database]

As you can see it will take ages to do upload content as I need to make all fields and maps.

Is there a way to make this process quicker?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's going to hard to see how you can improve its performance. --- "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add your code how are you trying to post data and getting it, and how your want to manipulate it.